# Prepend element in CSS, link not expanding to complete div

Tags: css, background-image, prepend

I'm sorry for this "abstract" title, I'll try to be as clear as possible ! :-)

I would like to prepend an image to some "special" links -- I've achieved the result with two solutions :

```
<a href="#" class="link1">My first link</a>
<a href="#" class="link2">My second link</a>
```

CSS

```
.link1 {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ea5c2a;
text-decoration:none;
color:#ea5c2a;
background:url('http://www.showbuzz.org/rjmd/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/pointeur_orange.png') no-repeat;
padding-left:15px;
}

.link1:hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid #ea5c2a;
text-decoration:none;
}


.link2:before {
content: url('http://www.showbuzz.org/rjmd/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/pointeur_orange.png');
}

.link2 {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ea5c2a;
text-decoration:none;
color:#ea5c2a;
}

.link2:hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid #ea5c2a;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Here's a working JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9g278/

I've got two questions:

1. What about performance issues between these two solutions? The first one uses a background-image (that doesn't repeat) and adds padding to the left of the link. The second one uses the pseudo-selector `::before`
2. As you can see, the text-decoration goes to the very left side of my link, including the background. How can I start the underlining from the beginning of the words, not the left side of the link itself ?

Thank you very much !